# vbs to detect usb drive and run some commands

Tags: windows, batch, vbscript

I have two scripts. Both are within the same folder on the hard disk. The "vbs" call "bat" to detect usb to run some commands.

I want to incorporate the function of selecting the usb to vbs. Thanks

usb.vbs

```
Option Explicit
On Error Resume next
mensaje = MSGBOX ("Start USB fix", vbOKCancel, "USB fix")
If mensaje = vbOK Then
SCRIPT = "usb.bat"
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 

NewPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, SCRIPT)
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
objshell.run NewPath, 1, true
    Else
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

usb.bat

```
@echo off
set /p drive=Choose the drive usb letter:
if exist %drive%: (goto target)
:target
attrib /d /s -r -h -s %drive%:\*.*
:: ext
call:ext "*.ini*"
call:ext "*.lnk*"
exit

:: funcion ext
@echo off
pause
goto:eof
:ext
set ext=%1
del /f/q/s %drive%:\"%ext%"
goto:eof
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:
no answer is correct.**

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more specific on **I could not make it work** phrase as it's too broad. Quote all error messages in particular…

Comment: would it be simpler to block all .ini, /.lnk with a antivirus rule for all usb disk ?

Comment: why not use applocker or software restriction policies (depending on OS) to do this?

Comment: For clarity, I have updated the question and scripts

Comment: @alejc **9×** changed question from that **2×**  altered topic. I gave answer to your original topic, then another answer to altered topic… Never more… If *any* answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important. Moreover, your question is off-topic here: questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow. Ask a new question there, pls

Comment: JosefZ. The answers to the original questions were not answered clearly and did not solve the problem. Therefore, i decided to rephrase the question to make it easier to answer.
If you do not agree with this change, then you can correctly answer the original question and I will select your answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. VBScript: please read Rob Haupt's [five VBScript 'best practices'](http://robhaupt.blogspot.cz/2008/07/my-five-vbscript-best-practices.html) and Rob van der Woude's [Debugging Your Scripts](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_debugging.php); in short:

   - use [`Option Explicit` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484(v=vs.84).aspx) *always* (if used, the `Option Explicit` statement must appear in a script before any other statements) and
   - use [`On Error GoTo 0` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53f3k80h(v=vs.84).aspx) at least for debugging; read example in [this my answer about VBScript error handling](https://serverfault.com/a/738844/257436).
2. Batch script: please read Rob van der Woude's [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php).
3. Why not to stay in a batch script for all given task? Let's apply [`wmic` command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html): the [Win32_Volume class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515(v=vs.85).aspx) (represents an area of storage on a hard disk) or the [Win32_LogicalDisk WMI class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx) (represents a data source that resolves to an actual local storage device on a computer system running Windows).

Try yourself *** see **edit** below:

```
wmic path Win32_Volume get BlockSize, DriveLetter, DriveType, Label
wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk get DeviceID, DriveType, Description, VolumeName, FileSystem
rem or full output:
wmic path Win32_Volume get /value
wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk get /value
```

Here's possible skeleton of your batch script (put it together with your `usb.bat` script *yourself*):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "_drives="
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('
  wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk where "DriveType=2" get DeviceID /value ^|findstr "="
  ') do for %%g in ("%%~G") do (
    set "__%%~g"
    echo(
    rem echo going to process drive __%%~g
    call :processDrive
  )

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:processDrive
  echo processing drive %__DeviceID%
  pushd "%__DeviceID%\"
    2>NUL dir /S /B /A *.ini
    2>NUL dir /S /B /A *.lnk
  popd
goto :eof
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the `DeviceID` value;
- `%%g` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned: `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

**Output**:

```
==> D:\bat\SF\786392.bat

processing drive F:
F:\Shortcut.lnk
F:\vbScriptDoc\Hey_Scripting_Guy.lnk

processing drive G:
G:\SPSS\admin\SCRIPTS.INI
G:\SPSS\admin\system32\GroupPolicy\GPT.INI
G:\VB_scripts\Net\nethood_create_a_link.vbs.lnk

==>
```

**Further resources** (required reading for a batch sripter):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`>>`, `2>NUL` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

*** **Edit**: unfortunately, querying `DriveType` property in both `Win32_Volume` and `Win32_LogicalDisk` wmi classes could give false results, see next output where both `F:` and `G:` are USB removable media so that `DriveType` property **should** be **2**:

```
==> wmic path Win32_LogicalDisk get DeviceID,DriveType,Description,VolumeName, FileSystem,Size
Description       DeviceID  DriveType  FileSystem  Size           VolumeName
Local Fixed Disk  C:        3          NTFS        119664537600
Local Fixed Disk  D:        3          NTFS        1000202039296  DataDisk
CD-ROM Disc       E:        5
Removable Disk    F:        2          FAT         519274496      KINGSTON
Local Fixed Disk  G:        3          FAT32       500044136448   GOG

==> wmic path Win32_Volume get BlockSize, DriveLetter, DriveType, Label, Capacity
BlockSize  Capacity       DriveLetter  DriveType  Label
4096       1000202039296  D:           3          DataDisk
4096       366997504                   3          Rezervováno systémem
8192       519274496      F:           2          KINGSTON
65536      500044136448   G:           3          GOG
4096       119664537600   C:           3
                          E:           5
```

You need to combine next WMI/WMIC queries to get right drive letters of removable disks:

```
==> wmic path Win32_DiskDrive get DeviceID, InterfaceType, MediaType

DeviceID            InterfaceType  MediaType
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  IDE            Fixed hard disk media
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  USB            Removable Media
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  IDE            Fixed hard disk media
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3  USB            External hard disk media


==> wmic path Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition get /value

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #0""

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #1""

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #2, Partition #0""

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0""

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE3""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #3, Partition #0""



==> wmic path Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition get /value

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #1""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:""
EndingAddress=120032591871
StartingAddress=368050176

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #0""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="D:""
EndingAddress=1000203091967
StartingAddress=1048576

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #2, Partition #0""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="F:""
EndingAddress=519569407
StartingAddress=16384

Antecedent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #3, Partition #0""
Dependent="\\USER-PC\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="G:""
EndingAddress=500105249279
StartingAddress=32256
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and for your great effort to explain, but it's not what I want. What I want is to fix the line that detects the USB drive letter:
(ObjDrive.DriveLetter & ": \ =" & objDrive.VolumeName, vbInformation, scriptBaseName) and add what is missing from "usb.vbs" to "usb.vbs" tell "usb.bat" what is the usb drive where it should run. It's all ("usb.bat" is correct)... sorry for my english

Comment: Your `usb.vbs` is not well-written. However, that problematic line is a parameter list of `msgbox` function. Compute `strDrive = objDrive.DriveLetter & ":\"` and then supply it to your  `usb.bat` script as follows: `objshell.run """" & NewPath & """ " & strDrive, 1, true` or even you could specify `objshell.run "cmd.exe /C """ & NewPath & """ " & strDrive, 1, true`.

Comment: Re-edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Here are my artless changes to your `usb.vbs`. Note that most `MSGBOX` are replaced as I hate all dialog boxes, popup boxes etc. if their output is useless in given context:

```
' VB Script Document
option explicit
'On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName

Dim objFSO, objShell, objDrive, scriptBaseName
Dim mensaje, SCRIPT
Dim strPath, objFile, strFolder, NewPath, strDrive, strcmd, iResult

mensaje = MSGBOX ("Start USB fix", vbOKCancel, "USB fix")
If mensaje = vbOK Then
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  scriptBaseName = objFSO.GetBaseName(Wscript.ScriptFullName)
      SCRIPT = "usb.bat"
      strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
      Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
      strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile) 
      NewPath = objFSO.BuildPath(strFolder, SCRIPT)
  For Each objDrive In objFSO.Drives
    strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & objDrive.DriveLetter & vbTab & objDrive.DriveType
    If objDrive.DriveType = 1 And objDrive.IsReady Then ''

      strDrive = objDrive.DriveLetter & ":\"
      '''xmsgbox objDrive.DriveLetter & ":\ = " & objDrive.VolumeName, vbInformation, scriptBaseName
      'strcmd = "cmd.exe /C """ & NewPath & """ " & strDrive ' executable
      strcmd = """" & NewPath & """ " & strDrive                 ' batch script
      iResult = objshell.run( strcmd , 1, true)
      strResult = strResult & vbTab & strcmd & vbTab & iResult
      '''CALL xMSGBOX ("Finish USB fix", VBOKONLY, "USB fix")
    End If
  Next
Else
  CALL xMSGBOX ("Cancel USB fix", VBOKONLY, "USB fix")
End If

'strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & 

Wscript.Echo strResult
Wscript.Quit

Sub xMSGBOX(byVal sPrompt, byVal sButtons, byVal sTitle)
  strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & "=" & sPrompt & " =" & sButtons  & " =" & sTitle  
End Sub
```

Tested using next `usb.bat`:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
echo 0th parameter = %0
echo     script = %~f0
echo parameters = %*
pause
ENDLOCAL
exit /B
```

**Edit** unfortunately, [`DriveType` Property of a `Drive` object in `FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys4ctaz0(v=vs.84).aspx) could could give the same false results as querying `DriveType` property in both `Win32_Volume` and `Win32_LogicalDisk` wmi classes. Cf output from above `786392.vbs` script (run on the same data as in [example in my other answer to current question](https://serverfault.com/a/786473/257436)). In fact, drive **`G`** here is an USB removable disk so that **should** be of `DriveType` **1**.

```
==> cscript D:\VB_scripts\SF\786392.vbs
786392.vbs
C       2       drive type=2
D       2       drive type=2
E       4       drive type=4
F       1       "D:\VB_scripts\SF\usb.bat" F:\  0
G       2       drive type=2
```

==>

Comment: Thanks JosefZ for your answers, but doesn't work. For more clarity, I have updated the question and scripts. Thanks again

Comment: @alejc the **doesn't work** phrase is indeed very exhaustive :)) For more clarity, this is my last post on current thread and question.

Comment: It's a shame I was not able to find the solution to what I want. Anyway, thank you very much for your help and time spent.

Comment: Note that desired drive specification is supplied to testing `usb.bat` as the first parameter so that you could use `set "drive=%1"` instead of `set /p drive=Choose the drive usb letter:`

Comment: Update the question